# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am using PHP 5 and trying to get the the currency exchange rates from a Web page using cURL.

To retrieve the contents I call:

```
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

This displays the page correctly. However, when I try to format it into XML using:

`$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);`

Numerous warnings are displayed ending with "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'"

I have used `stripslashes($html)` and turned off `magic_qoutes`...

Kindly help me finding a solution, I have been stuck on this problem for the past 2 days.

Also note, the page has the JavaScript embedded into it.. is this the JavaScript  that is not allowing the XML to be created?

Thank you

Comment: the question is: whats your aim? afaik the SimpleXML class requires valid structures. Since you get those errors I could imagine that the site is invalid. Did you already check this? And how could you want to have JS in you XML?

Comment: Thank you for ur time. My target is to extract data from currency-exchange website, this is the goal ...
the website is ` http://www.thecurrencyclub.co.uk/currency-exchange-rates-all-band.do ` and it looks nicely formatted ... 
as far as JS is concerned, i m new to curl so i was wondering that if this JS is not allowing to create XML. 
P.S JS is not needed

Comment: I dont know anything about the performance loss you could get but heres a simple dom parse which i use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

For most things this is much easier to handle. Anyway: For complex XML works you should try to get on with SimpleXML

Comment: The pager that you are trying to scrape isn't XML. Perhaps you you should look into HTML DOM parsing... http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Comment: thank you for ur time Malachi, i figured out that the page hasn't well formed XML, i changed the solution accordingly by manually extracting the data under certain tab.

Answer (score 3):

if you wan't to read xml data please follow those steps,

$xmlURL = "your xml url / file name goes here";

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xmlURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: text/xml'
    ));
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $error   = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $obj = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($obj);
    echo "</pre>"; 
}
catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e);exit;
}
```

You will get array formate of the whole XML file.

Thanks.